# How do I test if icalendar daylight saving works?

Tags: icalendar

I have code that generates icalendar events, including timezone definition for daylight saving.

Timezone for CET/CEST is defined this way:

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Prague
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZNAME:CEST
DTSTART:20160327T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
TZNAME:CET
DTSTART:20161030T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

While I believe that this timezone definition is correct and events will have correct offset during `STANDARD` time (works fine with CEST so far), what can I do to be sure?

I can manually set clock to 30. 10. 2016 3:00, but this way I can't simulate the 3:00 -> 2:00 offset transition that will automatically happen (due to NTP), because I'd have to then set clock manually back one hour, which I think will get me back in time hour before daylight time change.

Is there a way to spoof time with own NTP server or force OS (Linux in this case) to change time offset? Or any other trick to simulate time offset change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, eventually I figured it out myself.

For programs started in user session should be sufficient to set **USER** time zone (for example in KDE time applet). But in case of Lightning calendar in Thunderbird, you have to set timezone in Lightning's own settings. And don't forget to close Ligtning window and open it again to apply the change.

For processes outside of user session I assume you would have to change system-wide timezone.

And then set date forward/backward to whatever time you want to test.